# Moving data back and fourth between main application and library

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I’m looking for ideas on how to implement a certain bit of functionality for a program.

Basically, I have a main program/thread that makes an asynchronous call to a library (that I also have control over) to do some processing. However, from that call, I need the library to make a callback to the main thread every so often to get more data. How could I do this?

Comment: Start by sharing the code that you've implemented so far.

Comment: There is no way to answer this without knowing about the library. Show us the library and some code as to how you make calls please.

Comment: I could't post the library because its business logic and they don't like posting code. However, @john wu's answer was perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So pass a callback for the library to use. For example:

```
public class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        var library = new Library();
        library.Callback = GetMoreData;
        var task = Task.Run( () => library.Foo() );
        Console.WriteLine("Other thread is running.");
        task.Wait();
    }

    static string GetMoreData()
    {
        return "More data";
    }
}



class Library
{
    public Func<string> Callback { get; set; }

    public async Task Foo()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            var moreData = Callback();
            Console.WriteLine("Library received this data: {0}", moreData);
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/41g7L6)